# QtRuby: Check Box not toggling

Tags: ruby, qt, qtruby

I have created a Checkbox with label AVS . When I click the checkbox, I need the below block of code to be executed. I am neither getting any error, nor is the toggle working.

```
require 'Qt'
class Auth < Qt::Widget

slots 'on_toggled(bool)'

def initialize(parent=nil)
  super(parent)
  setWindowTitle("Org");
  setFixedSize 750,530

  avs_ui

  show 

end 

def avs_ui
  @label = Qt::Label.new "AVS?: ", self 
  @label.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
  cb = Qt::CheckBox.new " ",self 
  cb.setChecked false 
  connect cb, SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"), self, SLOT("on_toggled(bool)")
  @label.move 65,130
  cb.move 170,130
end 

def on_toggled state 
   if state 

   @lineedit = Qt::LineEdit.new(self)
   @lineedit.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 12)
   @label = Qt::Label.new "Address: ", self 
   @label.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
   @label.move 380,130
   @label.resize 170,20
   @lineedit.move 500,130

   @lineedit1 = Qt::LineEdit.new(self)
   @lineedit1.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 12)
   @label1 = Qt::Label.new "Zip Code: ", self 
   @label.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
   @label.move 420,160
   @label.resize 70,20
   @lineedit.move 500,160
   end 
end 

end 

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
widget = Auth.new
widget.show
app.exec
```

Can someone let me know what changes I should make so that, when I click the checkbox, I get the other required widgets?

Comment: Could anyone tell what changes I should make in the above code ? Would be helpful

Comment: On checking the check box, if I want new blocks to appear on a new window, yes I am.able to get it.
But not in the same window and in the position I want .
Any answer will be appreciated